# Does pdf has styles, headers and footers information as docx?

Tags: pdf

Does pdf has styles, headers and footers information as docx file have separate xml files for these?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic understanding of a defined file format.

Comment: @Jongware What's wrong in getting understanding of that?

Comment: This sort of questions is not in the scope of StackOverflow. Your status suggests you have not yet read the [About StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page; please do so soon. Then please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Okay, I need to compare two pdf's based on their content as well as styles and header footer thing programmatically. So, I need to understand the structure of the pdf and how it is storing the information. This quest leads me to ask this. Does it makes sense? Anyways thanks for your concern and it makes sense if someone reads it.

Answer (score 3):

Regular PDFs don't have styles, but different fonts (for instance Helvetica is one font, Helvetica-Bold is another font of the same family).
They don't have headers and footers, just like they don't have paragraphs, section titles, table rows or table cells. Everything you see in a PDF page, is just a bunch of glyphs and paths and shapes drawn on a canvas.

However: if your PDF is a **Tagged PDF**, the PDF contains something that is known as the `StructTreeRoot`. This means that, apart from the presentation of the content, you also have a tree structure that stores the semantics of the content. This structure contains references to the content on the different pages, allowing you (for instance) to find out which lines belong together in a paragraph, which parts of the page are "artefacts" (such as a repeating header or footer), which content is organized as a table, etc...

Tagged PDF is a requirement for PDF/A Level A and PDF/UA documents. A majority of the PDF files you can find in the wild aren't tagged (properly).